# CSS toggle switch works except on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I had tried this code for toggle switch circular, it works fine for android but it doesn't works fine for iOS.

Below is the reference of code which I have used to write the code below

[Reference from where code is used](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch)

code:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(33, 159, 243);
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: white;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
  transform: translateX(13px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 17px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch" data-align="right">
  <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" value="false">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: There is no JS in the above code. It is pure CSS

Comment: it is very hard to press on ios

Comment: The code at w3schools, not a recommended resource, works perfectly in Chrome and Safari on iOS 12. What problems do you have?